# setting dependency property in user control style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, controls

I implemented a user control with a dependency property that looks like this:

```
public partial class MyUC : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUC), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.White, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public Brush MyBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(MyBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    //...
}
```

and try to set this property in XAML as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Custom.MyUC"
         x:Name="myUCName"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Custom"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         TabIndex="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
         MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"> 
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MyUC">      
            <Setter Property="MyBackground" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>   

    <Border BorderThickness="0">
        //...
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

It compiles but when I run the app I get the following exception:

> Set property 'System.Windows.Setter.Property' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '..' and line position '..'."

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you're trying to apply a style with TargetType="MyUC" to an element of type UserControl.

The solution is to apply the style from outside of the control.  So for example when you use the control in another window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyUC">
        <Setter Property="MyBackground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:MyUC />
</Grid>
```

As a test I added this code to the user control:

```
public partial class MyUC
{
    public MyUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }   

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUC), 
        new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.White, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ((MyUC)dependencyObject).MyBackgroundPropertyChanged(
            (Brush)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue);
    }

    private void MyBackgroundPropertyChanged(Brush newValue)
    {
        Background = newValue;
    }

    public Brush MyBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(MyBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Which then results in the control having a red background.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks a lot for your answer. Is there another solution that is more object-orientated? E.g., I try to set the property MyBackground depending on a DataTrigger for data managed by MyUC. This should be done within the code of MyUC not by each application that uses MyUC.